# How to set another key to behave like a tab button?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, user-interface, numeric-keypad

I have a user interface created in HTML and working with Angular. I want to set one of the buttons from a numeric keyboard to behave like the Tab button.  I want user to be able to switch fields in the interface using one of the buttons from a numeric keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

Not possible - this article (http://www.howtocreate.co.uk/tutorials/javascript/domevents) explains (for security reasons) why your script can't simulate actual user interaction. You're going to have to simulate the "tab"s behavior instead (i.e focus in another field, etc.)